# Survival analysis for nested, censored and dependent data

Tags: r, survival, epidemiology, censoring, nested-data

I have to analyse the effects of different treatments on the survival of individuals for 1 week.

But:

- the data are '**grouped**': individuals were grouped by 10, and the survival probability is affected by the number of individuals who died already
- the data are **nested**: I've got replicates.
- the data are **right-censored**: I want to include the number of individuals who didn't die after a week.

I use R, and I can't really find any packages to use for my problem. Cohort ad frailty analyses dont seem to ba appropriate.

I was thinking maybe something from **epidemiology** for the first problem (and analyzing it as a 'contamination probability' or something).

Comment: What do you mean that you have nested data as a result of having replicates? What is replicated?

Comment: For each treatment, I tested several groups. And also, I have used different populations of two locations, so I need to nest the populations into the location. Is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I run an experiment like the one you are doing. For the analysis I recommend Cox proportional hazards regression with an interaction of covariate on mortality (time). Using some instructions like `cluster()`, `strata()` and `family()` in the model specifications maybe you will be able to analyze your data set. Also you can right-cesored your data.

I find the text of John Fox "Cox Proportional-Hazards Regression for Survival Data" (and a very good deep-in the maths) very useful for comprehensive analysis of the methodological approach.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @MarcoTulio. I have edited your answer to make the English smoother; please make sure it still says what you want. I also deleted your signature information. Notice that your username & avatar are automatically added to your answer. If you want to make more information about yourself available to CV users, add that information on your user page. Since you're new here, you should read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which covers topics like these.